# Dynamic variable names in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, dynamic-variables

I am reading from a comma seperated file and splitting the contents into an array. I am doing this in a while loop so I would want my arrays to have have a different name dynamically because the last line in the file end up overwriting my array content. Below is a fragment of my the code involved.

```
  TextView txt1;
  TextView txt2;

  Scanner in = new Scanner(result);
  in.nextLine(); //skip first line

  while(in.hasNextLine()){
    String line = in.nextLine();
    String []dataset = line.split(",");//store values in array

    txt1.setText(dataset[4]);//Should be 5th element of first line
    txt2.setText(dataset[4]);//Should be 5th element of second line
  }
```

As you can see from the above code I want to set the value of txt1 to a val in the first line of my file and similarly to the txt2. I read HashMaps or Maps or ArrayList would help me but I am not sure how to achieve this.

Comment: What is txt1 and txt2? You never declare them in your code snippet.

Comment: You'd do something like `mapVariable.put("txt1", dataset[4])`, but the question's a bit confusing, so I don't really know.

Comment: @duffymo as you rightly mentioned its a snippet txt1 and txt2 and just text lables in my application. You could just view them as System.out.println(dataset[4]); // the value of which should be from first line of file, similarly for txt2

Comment: As Ludwig asked, what are txt1 and txt2? Will there be a known quantity of them (e.g. UI controls), or arbitrary number?

Comment: They are UI controls, its a textView in my android app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what you want to do correctly it is you want txt1 to equal the 5th element in the array on the 1st line and txt2 to have the text of the 5th element on the 2ed line (your comment says 3ed element but the code is pulling the 5th).

This can be achieved with conditionals and a counter.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(result);
   in.nextLine(); //skip first line
   int count = 0;
   while(in.hasNextLine()){

      String line = in.nextLine();
      String []dataset = line.split(",");//store values in array
      if (count == 0){
          txt1.setText(dataset[4]);//Should be 3 element of first line
      }else if (count ==1){
          txt2.setText(dataset[4]);//Should be 3 element of second line
      }
    count++;
   }
  }
```

EDIT:

So now that I know you want an array of arrays the set up is easy. The outer array should be mutable if you dont know the amount of data you are processing before hand.

```
ArrayList<String[]> dataSet = new ArrayList(10000)//number should be a guess at the amount of data
Scanner in = new Scanner(result);
   in.nextLine(); //skip first line
   while(in.hasNextLine()){

      String line = in.nextLine();
      String []dataset = line.split(",");//store values in array
      dataSet.add(dataset);
   }
   txt1.setText(dataSet.get(0)[4]);
   txt2.setText(dataSet.get(1)[4]);
  }
```

if you wanted to you could also create these text labels and store handels to them in a similar manner and set the text as you go.

Comment: +1. I think this is a better answer than mine. I think I misinterpreted the question. If while loops on hasNextLine(), expecting attempting to set multiple values from the same line is ridiculous. Confusing question.

Comment: yea should have changed it. better to just call in.nextLine(); twice and store the data if your just interested in the first and second lines

Comment: @Tiksi, sorry about the confusing question but basically I think Michael got the point. To make it clearer since every time the loop runs I read a line from the file and therefore the content of dataset are overwritten by the values of the new lines. So I need to find a way of may be giving a different name to the dataset array e.g. dataset1, dataset2, dataset3, e.t.c as long a I read lines from the file. My code would have been txt1.setText(dataset1[4]) and txt2.setText(dataset2[4]); but this method is not possible in Java. I hope its clear now.

Comment: Thanks Michael, this is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 3):

You would need to add your dataset array to a list. So, before your while loop:

```
List datalist = new ArrayList();
```

Then, after:

```
String []dataset = line.split(",");//store values in array
```

Add:

```
datalist.add(dataset);
```

Answer (score 0):

Was going to comment on Michael's post, but not enough room! If you were expecting an arbitrary number of lines from your input, and want to process them outside of the loop, you could combine Michael's approach with mine and end up with:

```
   Scanner in = new Scanner(result);
   in.nextLine(); //skip first line

   List txtList = new ArrayList(); //create list

   while(in.hasNextLine()) {
     String line = in.nextLine();
     String[] dataset = line.split(","); //store values in array

     Text txt1 = new Text(); //assuming txt1 is an instance of "Text"
     txt1.setText(dataset[4]); //Should be 5th element of first line

     txtList.add(txt1); //add 5th element of each line to list
   }

   /*
    * txtList now contains instance of Text containing the 5th value from each
    * line of input
    */
```

Comment: thanks for the help its also another possible solution...